# Remove built in wordpress login and use only google auth

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I am using [Google apps login plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-apps-login/). I would like to keep this only as a login mechanism and remove the built in: **username/password** that appears below it.

How can I disable the wordpress built in authentication mechanism? by disable i mean disallow any manual forging of its login url request too.

Comment: This is actually a two part question.  One you need to customize the WP login screen to remove the WP login form.  There are plugins that will do it.  The second part is to remove the WP native auth. It is something simple like `remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password');`

Comment: To remove the login form is simple too, but the tricky part is that other authentication plugins, probably the GA login,  insert their links into the WP login form.  We used one of the WP login hooks, then added javascript to hid the loginform.

Comment: @user42826 thanks, i think i will edit wplogin.php for this case

Comment: Dont modify wp-login.php.  Every time you upgrade it will be written over.  This is why WP has hooks... the changes will persist even after upgrades.

Comment: Did you see the Google Auth example from the plugin creators?  They added javascript to hide the username and password parts of the form.  https://wp-glogin.com/wp-login.php

Comment: @user42826 oh no i didn't , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove WP native username/password authentication use the code below.  It can be added to the theme (functions.php), to a plugin, or mu-plugin.  Just make sure you have another authentication module working before you disable WP native auth.

`remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20, 3);`

Comment: I tried it in functions.php, it doesn't seem to work. I am using wordpress 4.1

Comment: It works for me.  I added it in a plugin and mu-plugins as a test.  Note that this does not change the login form.  It removes the WP native authentication.  If you create a user with a password try logging in with and without the remove_filter above.

Comment: ok didn't know that, thanks for the clarification. Worked like a charm

Comment: [It looks like this may have stopped working in Wordpress 5.6](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-password-login-hook-disapeared-in-wp-5-6/)