# Create new user without password

Tags: functions, user-registration

For a specific use case, I need to add users only by username and email without having to input a password for them.

Right now if i try to leave the password field empty, it displays an error.

How can I create a new user without having to put password without modifying the core? is it possible to remove these fields from the user add form?

**UPDATE: why do I need to do this?**

referring to my other [question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181114/remove-built-in-wordpress-login-and-use-only-google-auth), the google authentication plugin checks (After successful google authentication) if the google email used is found in wordpress, for a given user.

So i just need to create users locally with their usernames and email **only**. I need to remove the password fields from the form and disable the built in login mechanism (but the latter is related to my other question mentioned above).

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do it that way. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kaiser you are right, check my update.

Comment: How are you creating users?  There are a few ways to create users: registration, wp-admin, network wp-admin, API.  We setup our WP system to not use WP native auth either.

Comment: @user42826 right now am adding them manually from wp-admin. However if you have a better method for this scenario am open to try it

Comment: WP multiste allows admins to create users without a password.  We wrote our own plugin to add multiple users (no password required).  There are other plugins out there that will do the same thing.

Comment: @user42826 is your plugin available to the public?

Answer (score 5):

Current versions of WP allow creation of a user without creating a password. Just leave password area blank, and verify no password if prompted.

But, best practice might be to create user with a random password, but not tell the user the password. Have them do the 'lost password' thing to set up their own password. That's what I do for my users. I don't have to tell them a password (sending one via plaintext in an email is not good), and they are responsible for creating a password they can remember.

(Old question without an answer, but guidance is appropriate for current versions and anyone that finds the question.)