# New user form rejected because "passwords don't match"—but there's only one password field

Tags: users, admin, authentication

I am trying to add a user to a [blog of writings by or about my late father](https://Richard.HappyHobo.net).  One of the articles is by my niece, but I cannot add her as a user.  The admin form only has one field for password, but when I click "Add new user," I get "*Error: Passwords don’t match. Please enter the same password in both password fields.*"  Unfortunately, the form only has one password field!

[Another QA](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181127/create-new-user-without-password) says "Current versions of WP allow creation of a user without creating a password" but apparently, that is no longer the case.  5.8.1 outlines the empty field in red and puts an exclamation point in it, but doesn't say anything.

I can go into the database and create the user by SQL, but I don't know whether I would have to change other tables for DB integrity.

After I created the blog fifteen months ago, I was able to add an account for my father.  He is deceased, but I log in to that account when posting things he wrote.  I can't go back in time to see what the screen looked like fifteen months ago (actually, I could, if I were willing to spend ten minutes restoring a backup and ten more reversing it).  But here's what it looks like today:
[image][image]

Comment: This is an odd case... I'd be interested to see a screenshot of what the New User form looks like, as well as the error message you're seeing.  On a side note, I don't believe there's any reason you can't add a new user from the DB if you need to. I've done this in the past and didn't have any issues.

Comment: switching to Chrome from FireFox worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a direct solution to this, but I think I know what the problem is. I am guessing you were using Safari. I have just run into this problem myself. It's a bit maddening to get this message as there *is only one* password field.

I believe the issue is Safari's auto-suggestion of new passwords, which is a constant source of frustration for me with WordPress admin. I think this form may have a hidden password verification field, and Safari is stupidly interfering with the auto-generated password WordPress is creating, causing the visible and hidden fields to have different values.

I immediately switched to Chrome, tried creating a new user with the same credentials on the same site, and it worked just fine.

So ultimately this is a Safari issue. It would really be great if there were a way for WordPress to tell Safari not to enter its auto-complete suggestions in password inputs (i.e. if Safari would actually honor `autocomplete="new-password"`), or for users to tell Safari not to auto-generate passwords but still keep other form auto-complete turned on.

Comment: That's possible.  I worked around it.  Don't remember how, but most likely in SQL.

Comment: FWIW, if anyone else is having this problem, like room34 said this is a browser issue. It also happens in Firefox. If you open up Chrome, you can login and add a new user just fine.

Comment: same problem on Firefox and same solution with Chrome => browser issue

Comment: Even for chrome I see the same issue. My chrome version is : Version 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (x86_64)